# Having issues deploying server section of project onto Heroku

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

Currently trying to deploy the server side of my app on Heroku to no avail.

I've already included a valid start command in package.json but Heroku is still complaining about a missing start command. I've included a screenshot detailing my package.json along with my folder structure. I can also include the Heroku logs from CLI if needed.

[image]

Comment: Think I may have solved it. Moved server into its own folder and tried it again.

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Heroku need a `package.json` in the _root_ directory of your project. I'm surprised this is even being successfully deployed.